# how to create a jenkins job for a java project

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a java project which executes successfully in my local machine. I need to execute the same using a JOB via Jenkins. Your answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: the best way is probably to read the Jenkins documentation or a tutorial and try out yourself.

Comment: welcome to SO, show us what efforts you have put in ?

Answer (score 1):

This is well documented on the Jenkins website, and elsewhere.

Please see [Building a software project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) in particular, but also the [Tutorials Point Jenkins tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/index.htm) (there is a dedicated section for setting up build jobs, as well as sections on configuring Maven etc).